# Verifying that the Sobolev space is a Banach Space

Tags: banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces

In PDE Evans 2nd edition (pages 262-263), I am trying to understand a proof of a theorem, which states:

> **THEOREM 2** (Sobolev spaces as function spaces)**.** For each $k=1,\ldots$ and $1\le p\le\infty$, the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(U)$ is a Banach space.

My question concerns verifying the triangle inequality property, which is part of showing that $\|u\|_{W^{k,p}(U)}$ is a norm.

> Next assume $u,v \in W^{k,p}(U)$. Then if $1\le p < \infty$, Minkowski's inequality implies
>   \begin{align}
> \|u+v\|_{W^{k,p}(U)} &= \left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \|D^\alpha u + D^\alpha v \|_{L^p(U)}^p \right)^{1/p} \\
> &\le \left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} (\|D^\alpha u\|_{L^p(U)}+\| D^\alpha v \|_{L^p(U)})^p \right)^{1/p} \\
> &\le \left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \|D^\alpha u\|_{L^p(U)}^p \right)^{1/p} + \left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \|D^\alpha v \|_{L^p(U)}^p \right)^{1/p} \\
> &= \|u\|_{W^{k,p}(U)} + \|v\|_{W^{k,p}(U)}.
> \end{align}

Minkowski's inequality was used to justify the first inequality. But how can we justify the second inequality
$$\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} (\|D^\alpha u\|_{L^p(U)}+\| D^\alpha v \|_{L^p(U)})^p \right)^{1/p} \\
\le \left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \|D^\alpha u\|_{L^p(U)}^p \right)^{1/p} + \left(\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \|D^\alpha v \|_{L^p(U)}^p \right)^{1/p}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first inequality is the triangle (Minkowski) inequality for the $L^p$ norm, the second inequality is Minkowski inequality for the counting measure, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality.